# How did this answer get so many upvotes in only an hour?

Tags: support, up-votes, specific-answer

I just noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5859823/529618) received an impossible number of upvotes over the past hour or so.

I've seen popular answers before, but this just doesn't seem likely because:

1. The question was answered **exactly** one year ago today, which just seems like too much of a coincidence.
2. The topic has had no recent activity other than a stray vote every month or so.
3. Over 80 votes have been added at a rate of pretty much 2 vote per minute according to my [daily rep breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529618/alain?tab=reputation).
4. [I'm not John Carmack](https://superuser.com/a/419167)

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I might have thought it was a client-side problem, but I'm getting the badges for it and everything.

Comment: Because his VBA is well written and accomplishes a task without crashing or requiring administrator rights.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Might have *something* to do with the fact that [a link to that answer](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3926451) is the third item on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/news) at the moment.

Comment: @Alain: Bad news. This post here on Meta will draw **even more** attention to your answer.

Comment: Good find. I guess it was just a crazy coincidence that it was posted May 2nd of last year. Infinite loops are a scary thing. I'm always on my toes.